# How to make Kotlin getter give me actual data?

Tags: kotlin, getter

As I know, Kotlin generates getters when you invoke a class for the first time. So, for example, following code will always give me the same answer:

```
val instance
    get() = getFromDb() ?: MyData()
```

If there is a non-null `MyData` instance then it will give this instance all the time and if result from DB is null, I will always get new instance of `MyData`. I could be wrong here, so correct me if I am.

The question is how can I update the value of the getter? I.e. most of the time I want to get the data from database but after logout I want to request data from DB or just give me a new instance once again.

Comment: The way you wrote this, works like this:
If `getFromDb()` is not null it will return it otherwise it will return a new instance of class `MyData()`

Comment: Can edit your question and explain exactly what you need?

Comment: Also, it will call the getter (and hence call `getFromDb()` each time you try to access the property (not just the first time).  So it may _not_ always give the same answer.

Comment: @gidds
So, it doesn't store the fetched from DB data once and for all but it makes a DB request every time, right? And if I need to cache this data, I need to create a separate variable?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari
In other words, does Kotlin cache a value after first appeal and does it use cached value onwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly:

1. If the field is not null you want to get the value
2. If it is null you want to get it from the Database
3. If it does not exist in Database you want to create a new instance

And all of those instances should be saved to instance variable. If this is what you want you can do something like this:

```
var instance
    get() = field ?: getFromDb().also { field = it } ?: MyData().also { field = it }
```

Please noice the `var` instead of `val`